# Has this image of the Draco Constellation been altered

Tags: amateur-observing, constellations, visualization

Have the stars in this photo of the Draco Constellation been magnified so as to help me see the Draco or not?

[image: Potentially magnified photo of Draco]

Also I really like [this image][2] of Orion; if someone knows of a site with a lot of such images that are in a user friendly, easy-to-find format, I would appreciate it.

Comment: It surely is no Hubble photo, as you clearly see the tree on the lower part of the image...

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape He stated, that the Hubble photo is below. The tree is on the first image without him stating its origin.

Answer (score 2):

The image of Draco has definitely been altered.  Most of the stars in Draco are quite faint, even the ones making the dragon shape, whereas in the image they are all shown as bigger/brighter than the stars in Ursa Minor (the quadrilateral in the middle with 3 stars trailing down to the lower left.  The last of the 3 is polaris, which is in reality brighter than all the stars in Draco.
[image]

The same is true for Kocab.

The image of Orion is typical of probably thousands taken by amateur astronomers.  If you want to find others, try a search engine.  There may be some specific sites that collect all or most of the constellations, but I'm not aware of them.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I still can't figure out what's what; can you have pity on me and help me out by mentioning a specific pair of stars, one that appears much brighter than the other in the OPs image and is in reality less bright? Sorry but I'm not good with constellations. All I need is just the names of two stars; I'll do the rest on my own as "homework". *Thanks!*

Comment: Etamin looks brighter than Polaris.  Their respective magnitudes are 2.2 and 2.0.